# how do i extend pv when extending vmware disk?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, lvm

I extend the disk in vmware

[image]

after doing so I get the configuration but how to extend the pv /dev/sda1 at 30G to later extend the vg?

[image]

I don't want to extend the partition with fdisk I just want to extend the pv stop then extend the vg and lv later.

code continue but it tells me that the grub cannot be installed
error grub-install unable to identify a file system

i want this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see what devices you have:

`ls /sys/class/scsi_device/`

Hopefully this list corresponds to the connected disks as shown in the hypervisor. After you've performed this basic sanity check, you need to rescan the appropriate SCSI device. For example:

`echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/1\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan`

Now your operating system should see the new size of your drive. Check by running `fdisk -l` or `lsblk`.

At this point, your question becomes relevant: the lvm "physical volume" is a construct on top of either a partition or on top of a physical disk. As you've already partitioned SDA and assigned a `pv` to `sda1`, the only way to extend that particular pv is by first extending this partition - in other words exactly what you wanted to avoid.

Comment: it is about a partition but when installing ubuntu it is created as well as go so that lvm does not believe me on the disk ??

Comment: Well, with the default installation it looks that way. Without looking into it I don’t think you can (easily) do anything else with the disk that you boot from. The alternative is to do what @John Mahowald said in his post, and mount a separate vg-on-a-disk somewhere to use for data where you know you’ll need expandability.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to not use partitions, for data VGs.

Create a new disk. Do not partition it. Create a VG out of the entire disk. Use a persistent disk symlink for PVs, like `/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:03.0-scsi-0:0:1:2`, or perhaps it is reliably `/dev/sdb`. Create LVs and file systems.

Extending can be done by increasing the size of the disk, `rescan-scsi-bus.sh`, `pvresize`, and `lvresize --resizefs`.